# I can't write on file `elsarticle-template.spl'

Tags: errors, linux, elsarticle

I'm trying to compile elsarticle with a fresh texlive ubuntu repository distribution. it worked flawlessly on windows so my file is in order. Linux texmaker complains that

```
\immediate\openout\splwrite=\jobname.spl
```

in

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
```

can't be executed.
I have given everyone permission to write to the folder and all files and folders included, hoping it would fix the problem but it has not.

What is this splwrite and how can I fix it?

(edit) here's a log:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2016.3.30) 2 APR 2016 02:29
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**elsarticle-template.tex
(./elsarticle-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 7 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
\@bls=\dimen102
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen103
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
Package: pifont 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+pzd on input line 63.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+psy on input line 64.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
))
\c@tnote=\count88
\c@fnote=\count89
\c@cnote=\count90
\c@ead=\count91
\c@author=\count92
\@eadauthor=\toks15
\c@affn=\count93
\absbox=\box26
\keybox=\box27
\Columnwidth=\dimen106
\space@left=\dimen107
\els@boxa=\box28
\els@boxb=\box29
\leftMargin=\dimen108
\@enLab=\toks16
\@sep=\skip43
\@@sep=\skip44
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip45
\bibsep=\skip46
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count94
)
\splwrite=\write3
! I can't write on file `elsarticle-template.spl'.
l.645 \immediate\openout\splwrite=\jobname.spl
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name
! Emergency stop.
l.645 \immediate\openout\splwrite=\jobname.spl
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1365 strings out of 494976
16742 string characters out of 6179137
70916 words of memory out of 5000000
4635 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
4330 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
34i,0n,30p,249b,78s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

(edit) this is relevant dpkg -l

```
ii  libpod-latex-perl                           0.61-1                                              all          module to convert Pod data to formatted LaTeX
ii  libptexenc1                                 2013.20130729.30972-2build3                         amd64        TeX Live: pTeX encoding library
ii  luatex                                      0.76.0-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        next generation TeX engine
ii  preview-latex-style                         11.87-1ubuntu2                                      all          extraction of elements from LaTeX documents as graphics
ii  tex-common                                  4.04                                                all          common infrastructure for building and installing TeX
ii  texlive                                     2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
ii  texlive-base                                2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                            2013.20130729.30972-2build3                         amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-fonts-extra                         2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: Additional fonts
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended                   2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-generic-recommended                 2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Generic recommended packages
ii  texlive-lang-german                         2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: German
ii  texlive-latex-base                          2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-extra                         2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended                   2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-math-extra                          2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: Mathematics packages
ii  texlive-pictures                            2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
ii  texlive-publishers                          2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: Publisher styles, theses, etc.
ii  texlive-science                             2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: Natural and computer sciences
ii  texmaker                                    4.1-1                                               amd64        cross-platform LaTeX editor
ii  texmaker-data                               4.1-1                                               all          Texmaker LaTeX editor -- arch-independent files
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more details regarding the problem.  If you get any compilation errors, then please provide it.

Comment: Thanks Sun! The error was actually the title of the post. I have edited in a log, hoping this will be more clear now. The tex compiles fine under windows so I'm sure it's mainly a linux texlive problem.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use under Windows? You appear to be using TeXLive2013 under ubuntu -- any chance you could update to TeXLive2015?

Comment: thanks mico, on windows it's the most up to date from the distribution website. on linux this is in the default repositories while 2015 is not. but copying in the log I actually scrolled below the fatal error line where it said to rename the file. magically, that was all. linux seems to be unable to handle the default name while windows isn't. If the cap fits, wear it.

Comment: `I have given everyone permission to write to the folder and all files and folders included...` ***Don't!***

Comment: The error message does ***not*** say that `\jobname.spl` is in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls`. What makes you think this is the relevant location? Where is the template you are trying to compile? This should be in your working directory which should ***not*** be in `/usr/share` but in your home directory somewhere. (And if Windows lets you write to system directories, so much the worse for Windows. I don't think it does, but I'm not in a position to investigate.)

Comment: because the log says it loads /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls, the error occurs with no other document class and the /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls has the splwrite at exactly the position pointed out in the log. latex under linux is unable to compile a file called elsarticle-template.tex. that's what it comes down to. don't ask me why windows is able to do so. don't ask me why the package maintainer of any texlive package put the cls and sty files into the /usr.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to rename the file. that was all.

When the log says

```
Please type another output file name
```

one should do so.